# How can I specify the multi update option using the mongodb go driver?

Tags: mongodb, go

According to the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#std-label-update-multi), I need to use the `multi` option to update multiple documents at once on some operations ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811378/mongodb-not-pulling-from-array-when-no-filter-is-given/73811723#73811723)).

My project is in Go. Although, when i read through the driver documentation, I can't find any `multi` option. Here is the structure presenting the available options (official go driver code) :

```golang
type UpdateOptions struct {
    ArrayFilters *ArrayFilters
    BypassDocumentValidation *bool
    Collation *Collation
    Comment interface{}
    Hint interface{}
    Upsert *bool
    Let interface{}
}
```

How can still use it in my go project ?

Comment: `updateMany()` for the Go driver - [relevant documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/usage-examples/updateMany/)

Comment: No, it doesn't mention the `multi` option anywhere in that doc.

Comment: I think there is some confusion. Your question links to the '_deprecated_ `update()` method in `mongosh`_'. The `mongosh` shell, and therefore your doc link, is not relevant to your specific question about how to update multiple documents _using the Go driver_. Both my link and the one @Ado Ren has in their answer are to the `UpdateMany()` method _for the Go driver_ that you should use. Definitionally `UpdateMany()` does not need (or have) a `multi` parameter since it is implied by the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/usage-examples/updateMany/) on update many:

> You can update multiple documents in a collection by using the UpdateMany() method.

Example from documentation:

```golang
coll := client.Database("sample_airbnb").Collection("listingsAndReviews")
filter := bson.D{{"address.market", "Sydney"}}
update := bson.D{{"$mul", bson.D{{"price", 1.15}}}}
result, err := coll.UpdateMany(context.TODO(), filter, update)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: because user tought I was refering to `$mul` while in reality I'm pointing to `UpdateMany` method.